# CSS Only Landscape not working portrait working

Tags: css

```
@media only screen and (min-width:300px) and (max-width:667px) and (orientation: portrait) {Class goes here}


@media only screen and (min-width:667px) and (max-width:768px) and (orientation: landscape) {class goes here}
```

portrait view working good but landscape not showing any change even media query can't see in inspect code also.

Comment: What device and what viewport dimensions are you trying this on?  And how are all the other scenarios styled? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Is the `max-width` of the device/screen more than 768px? That's where I would start to troubleshoot.

Comment: Yes, it will be. Current device is iPHONE SE width:375px; and height:667px;

Comment: Please help I need to finish this today.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I actually tested the ranges:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:300px) and (max-width:667px)   {
   div {
      background-color: red;
   }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:667px) and (max-width:768px)  {
   div {
      background-color: green;
   }
}
```

They do work. But when I add the orientation, it fails to work on the portrait.

```
@media only screen and (min-width:300px) and (max-width:667px)  and (orientation: portrait) {
   div {
      background-color: red;
   }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:667px) and (max-width:768px) and (orientation: landscape) {
   div {
      background-color: green;
   }
}
```

Try to remove one of the orientation on the media queries. It could solve the problem. If you still want to leave the orientation condition, test it on a real device instead of a simulating tool.

Comment: orientation removed works fine. Thanks